# com.walmart.marketplace.sdk.cli.SDKClient not found

Tags: java, sdk, walmart-api

I use WalmartMarketPlaceAPI java SDK .
but it tell me this class 'com.walmart.marketplace.sdk.cli.SDKClient' not found, somebody can tell how to solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using JDK version 7 or 8 only.
Also please make sure you are using command 
mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dexec.mainClass="com.walmart.marketplace.sdk.cli.SDKClient" -Dexec.args="MarketplaceClientConfig.properties" 
instead of using mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dexec.mainClass=“com.walmart.marketplace.sdk.cli.SDKClient” -Dexec.args=“MarketplaceClientConfig.properties” (note the difference in quotes)

Comment: Hi, in order to make your answer more readable, check out Stack Overflow's [Markdown editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). You'll see how to properly post pieces of code on StackOverflow.